# Why won't CPU go over 25% when build says "loop parallelized"

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, parallel-processing

Was testing and timing some computations (was trying to find a for loop that runs 4 times faster when paralleled with all 4 threads on my processor) when I noticed that this one won't run at 100% cpu usage despite the compiler reporting that it was parallelized. It would only run at 25% cpu usage. Each core on my processor was supposed to have its own copy of arr4, a C style array allocated on the stack, and each core is supposed to modify each value of that stack array repeatedly. At the end, a timer prints the time taken in seconds. If the time with parallelization takes 40 seconds, I want the time of the for loop without parallelization to take just under 4*40 seconds, or 160 seconds. Optimization is set to max speed and the stack size on physical memory is set to 800 million Bytes (to prevent stack overflow). Anyway, here is the test code below...

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main (void)
{
    clock_t begin, end;
    double time_spent;

    begin = clock();
    {
        //int j;

        #pragma loop(hint_parallel(4))
        #pragma loop(ivdep)
        for (int j=0; j < 8; ++j)
        {
            int * __restrict const arr4 = (int *) _alloca(16000000*sizeof(int));

            for (int z = 0; z < 16000000; ++z)
            {
                arr4[z] = z;
            }

            #pragma loop(no_vector)
            for (int i = 0; i < 16000000; ++i)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 160; ++k)
                {
                    arr4[i] -= (7 - arr4[i] * 6 % (i+77) + 5 * 4 / 3 + 3 % 2 + 1 - (i+7));
                    arr4[i] += ((77 - 2 - (i+9)/2 + arr4[i]));
                    arr4[i] *= (8 - 2 + 6 % 3 / 2 + (i+6));
                }
            }
            printf(" %i ", arr4[((j+1)*666)%16]);
        }
    }
    end = clock();
    time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / ((double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    printf("Test1: time as a floating point type is %f \n", time_spent);
    return 0;
}
```

This revised example also yields the same 25% CPU problem.

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main (void)
{
clock_t begin, end;
double time_spent;

begin = clock();
int * __restrict const arr4 = (int *) _alloca(16000000*sizeof(int));

#pragma loop(hint_parallel(4))
#pragma loop(ivdep)
for (int j=0; j < 8; ++j)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 16000000; ++i)
    {
       int v = i;    // eliminate initialization pass (z loop)
       for (int k = 0; k < 160; ++k)
       {
           v -= (7 - v * 6 % (i+77) + 5 * 4 / 3 + 3 % 2 + 1 - (i+7));
           v += ((77 - 2 - (i+9)/2 + v));
           v *= (8 - 2 + 6 % 3 / 2 + (i+6));
       }
       arr4[i] = v;
    }
    //printf(" %i ", arr4[((j+1)*666)%16]);
}

end = clock();
//time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / ((double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
time_spent = (double)(end - begin);
printf(" %i ", arr4[666]);
printf("Test1: time as a floating point type is %f \n", time_spent);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you fix your indentation?

Comment: Yeah. Sometimes when you copy and paste in visual studio, the indentation doesn't copy over correctly.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you should not expect linear speed improvements as you add processors.  Doubling the number of cores available typically only improves execution by about 1.8 times under ideal conditions.

Think of it in people terms:  does doubling a 10 person dev team to 20 people automatically allow you to get twice as much work done? No, because communication and coordination become a larger task as the number of participants increases.

Second, you have a lot of non-computational stuff going on inside your timer loop.  You've got memory allocation and printf in your outer loop, and you've got multiple memory reads and writes in your inner loop. In particular, you are reading from a memory address, writing to it, reading from it again, etc. which may nullify some register variable compiler optimizations.

It could well be that your cpu is spending much of its time waiting for memory reads and writes to complete.

Since your modification of the data in the array does not appear to be visible to external observers, you should consider pulling the arr4[i] value into a local int variable and perform all the operations on that local int variable, then write the local int variable back to the arr4[i] memory address. This should reduce your memory load from 5 reads, 3 writes to 1 read, 1 write per inner loop iteration and eliminate costly read-after-write pipeline stalls.

Since these memory writes are taking place inside of the k loop, moving the initial load and final store out of the k loop will reduce your memory load from (5+3)*160 = 1280 memory I/Os per iteration of the i loop to 2 memory I/Os per iteration of the i loop. Oh, and the entire initialization loop (the z loop) can be eliminated as well, since the initial value is the iteration count. So, we can reduce memory I/Os to 1 per i iteration.

Something like this:

```
for (int j=0; j < 8; ++j)
{
    int * __restrict const arr4 = (int *) _alloca(16000000*sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < 16000000; ++i)
    {
       int v = i;    // eliminate initialization pass (z loop)
       for (int k = 0; k < 160; ++k)
       {
           v -= (7 - v * 6 % (i+77) + 5 * 4 / 3 + 3 % 2 + 1 - (i+7));
           v += ((77 - 2 - (i+9)/2 + v));
           v *= (8 - 2 + 6 % 3 / 2 + (i+6));
       }
       arr4[i] = v;
    }
    printf(" %i ", arr4[((j+1)*666)%16]);
}
```

The compiler cannot always make this optimization because memory writes are usually considered sacred because they can be observed by unknown parties outside of the current context. If you know more than the compiler about the situation, you can write better code than the compiler can.

Comment: I copied and pasted that over my previous parallelized loop. I built it. The output of QPar-report read that it was parallelized. Normally, when I test these sort of things, my CPU meter reads 100%. The CPU meter still stalls at exactly 25% for an extended period of time (over 1 minute) despite the change. I'm getting this same problem when I use OpenMP as well. If it helps, when I look at the resource monitor for the CPU, all 4 CPU's are working, but when CPU 0 works at 100%, CPU 1 works at 0% and vice versa. Where CPU 2 has a hill, CPU 3 has a valley. I don't know the explanation.

Comment: Try removing the printf from the outer loop and rerun the test. If that doesn't do anything, try removing the memory allocation from the outer loop. If that doesn't do anything, go back and make sure you're not running the test under a debugger. Debuggers foul perf tests.

Comment: On the previous version, removing the printf causes the execution time to read zero because the optimizer skips over the loop entirely. On this version, the CPU still reads 25% with printf commented out. Also, the test is running in release mode, O2 speed based optimization, whole program optimization (/GL), favor fast code, and enable parallel code generation all on.

Comment: Also, the same 25% thing keeps happening even after I move the array outside the outermost loop. I'll put the new version that still doesn't work up on the question's code area so it's visible.

Comment: What does execution look like without the loop pragmas?

Comment: Exactly the same as with loop pragmas, except that output from build says "loop not parallelized". The 4 CPU's in resource monitors are forming hills and valleys in their processor usage the same way they were when the build output said that the code was parallel.

Comment: Also, I don't expect 4X speedup - I was searching for a situation where nearly 4X speedup would occur. Of all of my parallel loops, a 3X speedup would have been an exception. Anyway, what bugs me about this is that the processor usually always goes to 100% with parallel loops.

Comment: I'm not familiar with QPar-report, but if it says the loops are parallel but the performance is identical to non-parallel loops (and if there is nothing in the loops (like a mutex lock) that would force serial execution), I question the QPar-report.